# How to display Firebase Parents elements in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I can display children elements when there is only one parent but I don't know how to display parents (foods)?

[This is an image of Firebase Database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpN9q.png)

Code :

```
private void loadOrders(String restaurantId) {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
            R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            requests
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderAddreess.setText(model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getUserId());
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                }
            });
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to identify a) what you want to see, b) what you are seeing, c: any error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is custom your Request.class like:

```
public class Request{
   private List<Food> foods;
}
```

Inside your Food.class is something like:

```
public class Food{
   private String discount;
   private String productName;

   // get & set method here
}
```

and then you can simply get foods like a

```
model.getFoods().get({position that you want}).getProducName();
```